# Calling 32-bit unmanaged DLL files from C# randomly failing

Tags: c#, winapi, unmanaged, dllimport

I'm having an issue when calling 32 bit [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi) DLL files from a C# web site. The code generally runs fine, but occasionally I get an error,

> *Unable to load DLL '': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

This issue persists until I recycle the application pool for the site, and then it works fine again.

On the same server, there is also a web service that is calling the same set of DLL files. This web service doesn't seem to have the same issue that the web site has.

Both applications are using [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 3.5, separate application pools on [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).

Here is the code I'm using to wrap the DLL files:

```
public sealed  class Mapper
{
    static Mapper instance = null;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    private Mapper()
    {
        SetDllDirectory(ConfigManager.Path);
    }

    public static Mapper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Mapper();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public int Foo(string bar, ref double val)
    {
        return Loader.Foo(bar, ref val);
    }
}


public static class Loader
{
    [DllImport("some.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "foo")]
    public static extern int Foo(string bar, ref double val);
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
double val = 0.0; 
Mapper.Instance.Foo("bar", ref val);
```

Why would it "randomly" *Unable to load DLL '': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).*?

The other problem is that I haven't been able to replicate the issue in the development environment. I thought that due to two applications calling the same DLL files, that there could be some locks occurring. To replicate this, I created an application that spawned multiple threads and repeatedly called the 32-bit DLL files, and then used the web site to call these same DLL files. I still couldn't replicate the issue.

Some possible fixes that I can think of:

1. Wrap the 32 bit DLL files in the web service (because the web service doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem). But this may be worthless if it turns out that the web service also fails.
2. Set up state server for the session state and periodically recycle the application pool for the site.This isn't fixing the problem, only avoiding it.
3. Wrap the DLL files in an EXE file, and call that EXE file. Then I *shouldn't* get the same issue. But this also seems like a hacky solution.
4. Implement the *mapper* class differently? But how else should I be doing the call? The other drawback is that other applications are using this mapper, so I'd need to change there code too.

What should I do?

Comment: post the fusion log of the exception please

Comment: Hey Jack, I'll see if I can set it up tomorrow, and get the error to occur then I'll post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue (it's stopped happening now), I left the mapper code as is, but in the calling application I manually set the path (even though the mapper DLL file does it most of the time).

So in the main application, I make a call to append the path of the directory where the DLL files are located.

```
private static void AddEnvironmentPaths(string[] paths)
{
    string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? string.Empty;
    path += ";" + string.Join(";", paths);

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
}
```

What's strange is that the mapper class works most of the time, but sometimes stopped. Adding the path with the above code seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what really causes this problem, but in my experience this error message can be caused by following reasons:

- The DLL file that you are using needed a runtime library which is not available at the time of loading it (like the Visual C++ runtime library). You need the exact version of the library. For example, if your DLL file is written with runtime Visual Studio 2008 SP1, you need exactly the same version.
- One of the dependencies of the DLL file is not available. You can check this by using [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker).
- Also, you have to be sure that your DLL file and the calling application all are 32-bit or 64-bit. Sometimes I get the same error when I want to call a 32-bit DLL file from a 64-bit application.

I know this is not truly your answer, but I hope it would help you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks Nima, the problem though, is that it works for some of the time, and then will stop working out of the blue. The dlls are def 32 bit.  I'll check those 32bit dlls for dependencies anyway. Thanks.